# Parse Cloud Code - Add To Array

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, cloud, parse-server

Tried loads of different variations with my cloud code and I can't get it to work. Basically I've got a push notification function, and in this function I want to add an object to a PFUser's array, but you can't use a master key in Xcode so here's what I have:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("iOSPush", function (request, response) {

console.log("Inside iOSPush");

var data            =   request.params.data;
var not_class       =   request.params.not_class;
var not_objectid    =   request.params.not_objectid;
var not_date        =   request.params.not_date;
var userid          =   request.params.userid;
var recipientUser   =   new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
recipientUser.equalTo("objectId", userid);

//  set installation query:

var pushQuery       =   new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
pushQuery.equalTo('deviceType', 'ios');
pushQuery.matchesQuery('user', recipientUser);
pushQuery.find({ useMasterKey: true }).then(function(object) {
    response.success(object);
    console.log("pushQuery got " + object.length);
}, function(error) {
    response.error(error);
    console.error("pushQuery find failed. error = " + error.message);
});

//  send push notification query:

Parse.Push.send({
    where: pushQuery,
    data: data
}, { useMasterKey: true }).then(function() {

    console.log("### push sent!");

    //  create notification:
    var notification = {
        "title": not_class,
        "body": request.params.data.alert,
        "class": not_class,
        "objectId": not_objectid,
        "date": not_date
    };

    //  get notifications:
    var tmp_notifications = recipientUser.get("notifications");

    //  add notification:
    tmp_notifications.push(notification);

    //  update with notifications:
    recipientUser.set("notifications", tmp_notifications);
    recipientUser.save();

}, function(error) {
    console.error("### push error" + error.message);
});

response.success('success. end of iospush');

});
```

The Xcode cloud function I have provides the correct information, the function gets to the end.. just the function is not setting the notifications for some reason

Answer (score 3):

I ended up figuring out the answer to this post myself. The reason this didn't work is because I needed to first fetch the user object in a separate query, then save it using the master key. I also found out that there's a function for appending data onto an existing array without having to create another one (parseObject.add()):

```
var userQ   =   new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
userQ.get(userid, {
    success: function(theuser) {
        console.log("### got userrrrrrrrrr!");
        theuser.add("notifications", n_object);
        theuser.save(null, {useMasterKey:true});
    },
    error: function(object, error) {
        // The object was not retrieved successfully.
        // error is a Parse.Error with an error code and message.
    }
});
```

This set of code was executed just before:

```
response.success('success. end of iospush');
```